# Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 127.0.0.0:5173

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, ecmascript-2016

after install project with tailwind with the command

`npm create vite@latest my-project -- --template react`

and after config tailwind, I tried to run my project but I got this error.

I tried to install with next too and got the same error

[image]

I tried to reset localhost name, but no success

tried another port [image]

but no success

**Solution**

it seems that something is running in my localhost so I changed to 127.0.0.1:8080

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a process listening on port 5173 already.

You can check what is running on that port with:

```
lsof -i:5173
```

Or try killing it with:

```
kill $(lsof -t -i:5173)
```